# Picking twice from a set vs. picking from a set and a subset: are the odds of getting the same element identical?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a set composed of **N** elements, and a non-empty subset of that set composed of **n** elements. I aim to compare two scenarios: in one, I'm picking a random element of the set twice, and in the other I'm picking a random element of the set once, and then picking a random element of the subset once. I want to compare the probability of picking the same element twice in both scenarios.

Now, if I remember my elementary school math correctly, the odds of getting the same element twice in the full set can be described by $$\frac{N}{N}*\frac{1}{N}=\frac{1}{N}$$ or, textually: you're picking a random element from the universe of possible elements on the first pick, and picking the very same element on the second pick. Easy enough.

The second scenario is a bit trickier, though. You'll have to pick a random element *already extant in the subset* on the first pick, and then pick the very same element, now in the subset, on the second pick. To calculate those odds, then, you can go with $$\frac{n}{N}*\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{N}$$ where we're limiting the possibilities of the first pick, and following the same logic as the previous scenario regarding the second pick, though now applied to the subset.

As anyone can see, though, the probability of both scenarios is *identical*. Is that correct? Am I misunderstanding something here? This feels counterintuitive as heck!

Comment: Imagine that you do this in the other order... you *first* pick from the subset of size $n$ and *then* you pick from the full set of size $N$.  Regardless what it was that you picked from the subset there will be a $\frac{1}{N}$ chance that what you later picked from the full set will match.  This is true also if you pick from the full set first and from the full set again later, regardless what was picked in first step there is a $\frac{1}{N}$ chance of it matching.

Comment: Now... picking from the full set followed by from the subset versus picking from the subset followed by from the full set... it should be clear that these give the same probabilities since there is an obvious bijection between the outcomes of the scenarios (*by just reversing the order in which the selections in each outcome are listed*).

Comment: Ooooh, that certainly helps make sense of things!